# Brace expansion not working in a script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, brace-expansion

```
for i in {1..40}
do 
   echo $i
done
```

I got

```
{1..40}
```

and I would like to have something like

```
1
2
3
and so on
```

so I can use the variable `i` inside a command's parameter.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash

Comment: This works with `bash`. What shell are you using?

Comment: How exactly are you running the script? it sounds like you may be forcing it to be interpreted by a shell that doesn't support brace expansion e.g. running `sh yourscript` instead of `./yourscript` (where `sh` may be another shell, such as `dash`).

Comment: I was using **#!/bin/sh** istead of **#!/bin/bash** at the beginning of my script.. my bad.. thanks !

Comment: To know more about this in Bash you can checkout [Bash manual - Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **bash** 3.0+ (as well as zsh and ksh93), `{1..40}` will expand to the numbers from 1-40 (inclusive).  In a **POSIX shell** like dash (which is typical of `/bin/sh` in e.g. Ubuntu), it will not work (we call this issue a "bashism").

On systems with the GNU utilities, you can use `seq` to accomplish this:

```bsh
for i in $(seq 1 40)
do
    echo $i
done
```

To be more portable, you'll have to manually increment `$i` in a `while` loop:

```bsh
i=1
while [ $i -le 40 ]
do
    echo $i
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

This portable version is also very slightly faster since it lacks the external command.

Comment: Your `while` could be `i=; until [ "$((i+=1))" -gt 40 ]; do echo "$i". done` and, if run in `dash` is likely faster than anything you would run in `bash` anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv: The `$((i+=1))` syntax has been unreliable in my past experiences with older UNIX systems.  I don't like `until`, especially when `while` will work fine: try `i=0; while [ $((i+=1)) -le 40 ]; do echo $i; done`

Comment: Ok. The `until`, `while` stuff is just style, but what's unreliable about the increment += assign? Basically any of those assignments you can do in C you should be able to do in the shell. `|=` `^=` `&=` `/=` `*=` `-=` `%=`. That is, you can do them in a POSIX shell. But you should quote the math expansion in the `[` test `]` maybe if you don't get explicit about `$IFS` before hand.

Comment: some UNIX systems aren't fully POSIX compliant and miss this particular capability.  I'm no longer an admin, and I can't recall which ones, but I've definitely learned not to use assignment inside `$(())` notation.  Interesting note about quotation, but if `$IFS` is tampered with, a **lot** will break; `[` is the least of your worries ;-)

Comment: Well, today, it works in ksh93, zsh, mksh, posh, yash, bash, dash... and maybe I'm forgetting one or two. In `posh` though it won't like `v=; : "$((v+=1))"` *(though it should)* but instead prefers `v=0; : "$((v+=1))"`.

Comment: Again, I don't recall which, but it'd be one of the older commercial UNIX implementations of `/bin/sh`, quite possibly the very non-POSIX `jsh` that Solaris uses (or used to use?  I'm rusty) as `/bin/sh`

Comment: @AdamKatz If you're worried about the pre-POSIX `/bin/sh` on some unices, you can't even use arithmetic expansion.

Comment: `jsh` was used in Solaris 10 (well after POSIX was standardized).  @Gilles, sorry my memory is shot, but I seem to recall some `/bin/sh`s that support `i=$((i+1))` but not `$((i+=1))`.  `$((i++))` and `$((++i))` are rarer still.

Comment: Adam - `++i`, `i++` are not POSIX. *The arithmetic expression shall be processed according to the rules given in [Arithmetic Precision and Operations](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap01.html#tag_01_07_02_01) , with the following exceptions: Only signed long integer arithmetic is required. Only the decimal-constant, octal-constant, and hexadecimal-constant constants specified in the ISO C standard, Section 6.4.4.1 are required to be recognized as constants. The `sizeof()` operator and the prefix and postfix `++` and `--`operators are not required.*

Comment: @mikeserv - I never said they were POSIX.  I said they were rare.  Your quote seems to imply they are specified by POSIX yet not required, but again that does not change my earlier comments.  I haven't exhaustively checked, but it looks like all of the shells you tested are F/OSS that came out ~recently (post-Linux) whereas I'm referring to [POSIX-compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#Fully_POSIX-compliant) proprietary implementations from the 90s.

Comment: Adam - makes sense. Any currently POSIX-compliant shell will meet those minimum requirements these days, but probably not in those.