# copy files and append in another directory?

Tags: file-copy, cat

I have five directories Dir1, Dir2, Dir3, Dir4, Dir5. In each directory, I have five text files (which are named as file1.txt, file2.tx,.file5.txt) that contain data. What I want is to copy file1.txt from all the five directories and append them one after another in a different directory (named as Joint_Dir). Do the same fro file2.txt, file3.txt...file5.txt.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [globbing-patterns/wildcards](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm). For example, the following will concatenate all of the `file1.txt` files into a single file in the `Joint_Dir` directory:

```bsh
cat Dir[1-5]/file1.txt > Joint_Dir/file1.txt
```

But before using pattern-matching to execute commands like this I would run a couple of sanity-check commands to verify which files will be affected. In this case you can check that the pattern `Dir[1-5]/file1.txt` matches the expected files by using `ls`:

```bsh
ls -ld Dir[1-5]/file1.txt
```

Another option would be to use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html). Rewriting the previous example using brace expansion yields the following:

```bsh
cat Dir{1..5}/file1.txt > Joint_Dir/file1.txt
```

Note that brace expansion is a so-called [bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) and may not work in a different shell. This distinction has been discussed elsewhere, e.g. [Brace expansion not working in a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192464/brace-expansion-not-working-in-a-script). As discussed in that post, other alternatives include using the `seq` command or incrementing a variable inside of a while-loop.

Speaking of loops, if you want to perform all of the concatenations in single command you might use a for-loop, e.g.:

```bsh
for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    cat Dir[1-5]/file${i}.txt > Joint_Dir/file${i}.txt
done
```

---

What follows is a self-contained example illustrating how to use the above technique. You should be able to run the following as-is. First, here is a script to setup a directory with test files mirroring what was described in the original question:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create-test-files.sh

# Create test files and directories
for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    mkdir -p "/tmp/test/Dir${i}"
    for j in $(seq 1 5); do
        echo "File ${j} in directory ${i}" > "/tmp/test/Dir${i}/file${j}.txt"
    done
done
```

After running this script, we can check what was just created:

```
$ bash create-test-files.sh

$ tree /tmp/test/
/tmp/test/
|-- Dir1
|   |-- file1.txt
|   |-- file2.txt
|   |-- file3.txt
|   |-- file4.txt
|   `-- file5.txt
|-- Dir2
|   |-- file1.txt
|   |-- file2.txt
|   |-- file3.txt
|   |-- file4.txt
|   `-- file5.txt
|-- Dir3
|   |-- file1.txt
|   |-- file2.txt
|   |-- file3.txt
|   |-- file4.txt
|   `-- file5.txt
|-- Dir4
|   |-- file1.txt
|   |-- file2.txt
|   |-- file3.txt
|   |-- file4.txt
|   `-- file5.txt
`-- Dir5
    |-- file1.txt
    |-- file2.txt
    |-- file3.txt
    |-- file4.txt
    `-- file5.txt

5 directories, 25 files
```

We can also check the contents of the files:

```
$ cat /tmp/test/Dir[1-5]/file1.txt 
File 1 in directory 1
File 1 in directory 2
File 1 in directory 3
File 1 in directory 4
File 1 in directory 5

$ cat /tmp/test/Dir1/file[1-5].txt
File 1 in directory 1
File 2 in directory 1
File 3 in directory 1
File 4 in directory 1
File 5 in directory 1
```

Next we can create the following script to concatenate the files:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# concatenate-test-files.sh

# Create output directory
mkdir -p /tmp/test/Joint_Dir

# Concatenate identically-named files from different directories
for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    cat "/tmp/test/Dir"[1-5]"/file${i}.txt" > "/tmp/test/Joint_Dir/file${i}.txt"
done
```

After running this script we can check the contents of the output directory:

```
$ bash concatenate-test-files.sh

$ ls -1 /tmp/test/Joint_Dir/
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt

$ cat /tmp/test/Joint_Dir/file1.txt 
File 1 in directory 1
File 1 in directory 2
File 1 in directory 3
File 1 in directory 4
File 1 in directory 5
```

Once we're done experimenting we can delete the test directory:

```
rm -rf /tmp/test
```

Comment: Tried both codes, however, it is copying file1.txt of Dir1 over and over 5 times. similarly, file2.txt of Dir1 is appended 5 times. I want file1.txt of Dir2 to be placed below of file1.txt of Dir1. likewise for other files and directories.

Comment: What's the output of `ls Dir[1..5]/file1.txt`?

Comment: DIR1/FLOW_OUT_1.txt  DIR2/FLOW_OUT_1.txt  DIR3/FLOW_OUT_1.txt  DIR4/FLOW_OUT_1.txt  DIR5/FLOW_OUT_1.txt. I name dir as DIR. Also, file1.txt is actually my FLOW_OUT_1.txt

Comment: So, as you can see, you're getting the correct list of files for the concatenation, no? Have you double-checked to make sure that these files contain the text that you think they should?

Comment: Indeed. I get the correct list, however, when I run your code for concatenation, then it spits out the result with FLOW_OUT_1.txt of DIR1 being concatenated five times. I checked the files again, they are correct.

Comment: The file in each directory has the same name. Could that be a reason of concatenating the first file over and over??

Comment: @Ameer I just added a fully worked out example. Can you work through the example and verify that you get the same results?

Comment: Igal, that is a super explanation. Is there a way, I can send you my files? they are not heavy though.

Comment: You can update your question to include the file contents if you want, but I really don't think that should be necessary. I also think that it may be unhelpful, since it will add extraneous details. Are you getting the same results as described in my example?

Comment: I created the script files using the `vi create-test-files` and copied your code of files generation inside and then tried to execute it from the terminal `./create-test-files.sh`. However, it gives me the message as permission denied. Then i used the `chmod +x create-test.files.sh` to grant permission and tried again. however, no success. tried the bash command too.

Comment: I'm assuming this was a typo, but just to be sure, if you named the file `create-test-files` then you can't run it as `./create-test-files.sh` - the file name has to match exactly. If you're getting a "permission denied error" then it might be because you don't have write permissions to the `/tmp` directory. You can check that with `ls -ld /tmp`. If that's the case the you can try running this first: `sudo mkdir -p /tmp/test; sudo chmod ugo+rw /tmp/test`. That will create the `/tmp/test` directory with the necessary permissions.