# cat: append a text file in another folder as Dolphin action

Tags: cat, dolphin

How can I append an md-file to another md-file *in a subfolder* **as Dolphin action**?
I tried `cat %U >> subfolder-name/%u`, but I get this error message:
    `cannot create subfolder-name//path/to/md-file/md-file.md: Directory nonexistent`.
([this is not working for me](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399570/copy-files-and-append-in-another-directory))

### provisory workaround

Symlink destination file in the starting folder (calling it file-name.md.olon") and use
 `cat %U >> %u.olon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message

```
cannot create subfolder-name//path/to/md-file/md-file.md
```

the placeholder `%u` is replaced with an absolute path and a directory `subfolder-name/path/to/md-file` does not exist. If you want to create a file `subfolder-name/md-file.md` you can use `basename`

```
cat %U >> subfolder-name/$(basename "%u")
```

Comment: @Duns If it works you may accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Before executing the command in directory subfolder

First check whether directory exsists or not then go ahead for executing the command

below is script format for the same

if [[ -d subdirectoryname ]]
then
mention commands which is required
else
echo "subdirectory doesnt exists"
fi
```